# iPhone: How to ensure iBook files are stored locally

Tags: iphone, storage, books

There was a bug in iBooks. When file storage capacity is low, iOS deletes some iBooks files. The bug was that it deleted many files even if storage capacity was ok.

And I lost a bunch of PDF stored locally on my iPhone.

Today I synced again a few PDFs from Mac iBook  →  iPhone iBook.

Have two questions

- how to check reliably that files are stored locally on iPhone (ie not iCloud)? I mean, I could use the airplane mode and see if files are still openable ... but maybe there is a cache or something.
- actually, how to reliably use *only* local files - and get rid of iCloud access, at least for iBooks [ iCloud is <kbd>off</kbd> on my iPhone for iBooks, but files disappeared anyway ]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related question: [Books automatically deletes my books when offline, and when there is enough space on device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344271/books-automatically-deletes-my-books-when-offline-and-when-there-is-enough-space)

> how to check reliably that files are stored locally on iPhone (ie not iCloud)? I mean, I could use the airplane mode and see if files are still openable ... but maybe there is a cache or something

If you are on iOS 12, then go to library and next to the book at the bottom-left there will be a cloud symbol if it is stored in iCloud and no cloud symbol if it isn’t.

> actually, how to reliably use only local files - and get rid of iCloud access, at least for iBooks [ iCloud is off on my iPhone for iBooks, but files disappeared anyway ]?

Got to Settings -> [your name] -> iCloud and make sure Books is turned off.

**Note:** make sure you download all your Books before turning it off.

Comment: Really odd that Apple offloads *books*, of all things, so aggressively. Of all forms of media, text takes up the least storage space.